# Java Batch Compiler - ignore all warnings through command line option

Tags: java, javac, java-batch

I see these runtime programming options:
https://help.eclipse.org/2018-12/index.jsp?topic=%2Forg.eclipse.jdt.doc.user%2Ftasks%2Ftask-using_batch_compiler.htm

but I am wondering if there is a command line flag I can use to ignore warnings outputted by the compiler  (I just want to see errors).

For example I see:

```
----------
59. WARNING in /home/oleg/codes/oresoftware/vertx.api/src/main/java/huru/middleware/ErrorHandler.java (at line 16)
        HttpServerRequest request = ctx.request();
                          ^^^^^^^
The value of the local variable request is not used
----------
60. WARNING in /home/oleg/codes/oresoftware/vertx.api/src/main/java/huru/util/Asyncc.java (at line 121)
        public static AsyncTask zoom() {
                      ^^^^^^^^^
Asyncc.AsyncTask is a raw type. References to generic type Asyncc.AsyncTask<T,E> should be parameterized
----------
61. WARNING in /home/oleg/codes/oresoftware/vertx.api/src/main/java/huru/util/Asyncc.java (at line 124)
        v.done(null, null);
        ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
Type safety: The method done(Object, Object) belongs to the raw type Asyncc.IAsyncCallback. References to generic type Asyncc.IAsyncCallback<T,E> should be parameterized
----------
62. ERROR in /home/oleg/codes/oresoftware/vertx.api/src/main/java/huru/util/Asyncc.java (at line 131)
        Asyncc.Parallel(asList(
               ^^^^^^^^
```

Only looking to see ERRORs, not WARNINGs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

looks like `javac -nowarn` does the trick, also should work with other java compilers besides javac.

The option is mentioned here:
https://help.eclipse.org/neon/index.jsp?topic=%2Forg.eclipse.jdt.doc.user%2Ftasks%2Ftask-using_batch_compiler.htm